# THREEJS implementation of IfcAxis2Placement3D and IfcObjectPlacement

Tags: three.js, ifc

I am working on a webgl viewer of IFC file now. Most IfcRepresentation objects are easy to understand, however, I am not good at coordination transformation. Are there any better expression to translate and rotate an Object3D in THREEJS as defined by IfcAxis2Placement3D? I guess it should rotate the object by Z axis then align the Z axis to a new vector, how to implement this ?
Another questions is about IfcObjectPlacement. It always requires a sub PlacementRelTo object until PlacementRelTo == null. I am a bit confused again, is it a forward transformation or backward transformation if I want to read the absolute coordinates from this placement? I mean, use a push-pop or a direct order? for example, if there are matrix like M1, M2.. Mn, then M = M1 x M2 x ... Mn or M = Mn x Mn-1 x ... x M2 x M1? I can find beautiful mesh objects in my project but the position is always wrong. Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this article on matrix transformations for projection](http://www.codinglabs.net/article_world_view_projection_matrix.aspx) for a primer on Matrix transformations.

It's worth noting that most geometry in an IFC model will be 'implicit' rather than 'explicit' shapes. That means that extra processing needs to be performed before you can get the data into a form you could feed into typical 3D scene - and so you'll be missing a lot of shapes from your model as few will be explicitly modelled as a mesh. The long and short is that geometry in IFC is [non-trivial](http://www.buildingsmart-tech.org/ifc/IFC4/Add1/html/link/ifcgeometryresource.htm) [(diagrams)](http://www.buildingsmart-tech.org/ifc/IFC4/Add1/html/annex/annex-d/ifcgeometryresource/index.htm). That's before you start on placement/mapping/ transformation to a world coordinate system.

It's not clear if you are using a IFC toolkit to process the raw IFC STEP data. If not, I'd recommend you do as it will save a lot of work (likely years of work).

BuildingSmart maintain a [list of resources](http://www.buildingsmart-tech.org/implementation) to process IFC (commercial and open source)

I know the following toolkits are reasonably mature and capable of processing geometry. Some already have WebGL implementations you might be able to re-use.

- http://ifcopenshell.org/ifcconvert.html & https://github.com/opensourceBIM
- https://github.com/xBimTeam/XbimGeometry (disclosure - I am involved with this project)
- http://www.ifcbrowser.com/

Comment: Finally I made it. Try this out: http://hestia.tv/dhm4/ Thanks your answer although non of the resources helped much, I figured it out and I think I can push it even further. Many thanks and merry Christmas ! :)